# Facebook Graph API getting Data by Query from anywhere in User Description , location etc

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are using Facebook Graph API , And we want to search like "People who like bitcoin " , in Facebook search bar it show data after study from this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search

then we can find user from its name like [https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bitcoin&type=user&access_token=xxxxx...](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bitcoin&type=user&access_token=xxxxx....)

this works but if we pass query like [https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=people+who+like+bitcoin&type=user&access_token=xxxxx...](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=people%20who%20like%20bitcoin&type=user&access_token=xxxxx...)

It does not provide any data , but on facebook search it show data

Is it possible to get data that provide by facebook search bar ?

Comment: Of course your query does not work, because the `type` is still `user` … so you are searching for a user with the _name_ `people who like bitcoin` right now. And no, _Graph Search_ functionality is not available via API.

Comment: So how to find user in which it finds from people from its description , city etc ?

Comment: Not at all – the search functionality of the API is limited to what is documented in the first link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between what is possible on the facebook.com website, and what is available via the Graph API.

You already provided the link to the correct reference docs. Everything which is possible concerning search via the Graph API is documented there. Further from that, there are no other possibilities.